# Make clickable links using indices of associative array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress, hyperlink

I have an associative array of links like this

```
$my_links = [
       'city 1' => 'http://link1',
       'city 2' => 'http://link2',
       'Head Office' => 'http://link3'
    ];
```

and some html like this. **The html is dynamically generated by a script ( wordpress blog content)**.

```
<p>
   You can visit our stores at City 1 
   and City 2, 
   or visit our Head office.
</p>
```

**Required Output:** Make clickable links using indices of above `array`

```
<p>
   You can visit our stores at <a href="http://link1">City 1</a>
   and <a href="http://link2">City 2</a>, 
   or visit our <a href="http://link3">Head office</a>.
</p>
```

How to achieve this using `PHP` and/or `JQuery`?

Comment: do like this `<p>
   You can visit our stores at <a href="<?php echo $my_links['city 1'];?>">City 1</a> 
   and <a href="<?php echo $my_links['city 2'];?>">City 2</a>, 
   or visit our <a href="<?php echo $my_links['Head Office'];?>">Head office</a>.
</p>`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and Edit. The html is dynamically generated by a script ( from a wordpress blog content). Updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 

$my_links = [
       'city 1' => 'http://link1',
       'city 2' => 'http://link2',
       'Head Office' => 'http://link3'
    ];


$str = "<p>
   You can visit our stores at City 1 
   and City 2, 
   or visit our Head office.
</p>";


foreach ($my_links as $link_title => $link) {
    $str = str_ireplace($link_title,"<a href='$link'>".ucwords($link_title)."</a>",$str);
}

echo $str;
```

Loop over your `$my_links`. Find the link title present in the string and use [str_ireplace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) to replace the link title with the anchor tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 3):

Just use the array references:

```
<p>
   You can visit our stores at <a href="<?php echo $my_links['city 1']; ?>">City 1</a>
   and <a href="<?php echo $my_links['city 2']; ?>">City 2</a>, 
   or visit our <a href="<?php echo $my_links['Head Office']; ?>">Head office</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The html is dynamically generated by a script ( from a wordpress blog content). Updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

If your content is coming from PHP, use PHP's [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

This function's three parameters search the purpose:

> 1. search: string or array
> 2. replace: string or array
> 3. actual string: string

If `search` and `replace` are arrays, their elements count should be same.

Now, find the string segments like City 1, City 2 and Head Office and replace them by adding `<a href="...` to them.

Code:

```
<?php
$my_links = [
       'city 1' => 'http://link1',
       'city 2' => 'http://link2',
       'Head Office' => 'http://link3'
    ];
$content = '<p>
   You can visit our stores at City 1 
   and City 2, 
   or visit our Head office.
</p>';

$find = ['City 1', 'City 2', 'Head office'];
$replace = [
'<a href="'.$my_links['city 1'] . '">City 1</a>',
'<a href="'.$my_links['city 2'] . '">City 2</a>',
'<a href="'.$my_links['Head Office'] . '">Head Office</a>',
 ];
echo  str_replace($find, $replace, $content);
?>
```

A Quick Update:

Please use [str_ireplace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) instead of `str_replace()` discussed above as we have case insensitive comparison e.g. `city 1` vs `City 1`. This function works the same way as `str_replace()`, only it is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<p>
   You can visit our stores at <a href="<?=$my_links['city 1']?>">City 1</a>
   and <a href="<?=$my_links['city 2']?>">City 2</a>, 
   or visit our <a href="<?=$my_links['Head Office']?>">Head office</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The html is dynamically generated by a script ( from a wordpress blog content). Updated my question.